# CSS: Resize an element without moving the contents

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a piece of code that has a div with a certain width and height. That div also has a `CSS` animation, shrinking the div to nothing. However, the text wraps. I do not want the text inside to wrap. I will create a fiddle for a demonstration:

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/MashedPotatoes/vx9ernsk/)

I have attempted `overflow: hidden`, but the text still wraps eventually.

I apologize in advance if I'm missing something obvious, and thanks in advance.

Any `Javascript` solution (Unless it's adding classes or something) is not preferred, as `CSS` animations are much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added another div inside the main div and placed the text inside of that and it seems to be doing what you want it to do.

```
<div id="bar">
    <div style="width:250px; height:250px;">Good Day.
        <br/>
        <br/>I'm a DIV
        <br/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br/>And I shouldn't move when animating.</div>
</div>
```

give that a shot.  Text will always adjust to its' container, doing it like this places it inside of another container that remains the size you want it and because you have the overflow set to none on the outer container no scroll bar pops up when it shrinks smaller than the inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `white-space` CSS property and set the value to `nowrap`:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Because the text won't wrap now, you'll have to remove 'overflow:hidden' to see the rest of the text, or increase the width of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#bar`

Comment: You mentioned the same thing to the person below. However, it makes the last line wrap to the outside of the div, where you can't see the text.

Comment: Add a `<p>` tag around the text and give it a width in % less than 100 to your liking, and remove `width:250px` from `#bar`.

Comment: Can you attach a fiddle?